# Rotate a video and fit it to screen using CSS

Tags: html, css, video, mp4

I have the following style:

```css
video {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This is the video element:

```html
<video id="myVideo" src="/Space4.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

This seems to rotate and center the video, but it is almost 1/4 of the screen size. How can make it fit to screen?

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsrh7xgy/). This does not seem to be happening...

Comment: I want to stretch and fit the video for full screen

Comment: Vertically or horizontally?

Comment: both sides.. I would like the video to fill the screen

Comment: This is not fitting the screen because `video` has a default property `object-fit` set to `contain`

Comment: I changed it to fill and it only stretches the height and not the width. How can I stretch both ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a case where the new CSS3 units come in handy. If you just use normal percentages to specify the `width` and `height` of the `<video>` element, they will default to associating these dimensions with their viewport counterparts - but only prior to the rotation. So after rotation, these values will no longer correspond correctly to the viewport dimensions.

Since you actually want the opposite in this case, you can use `height: 100vw` and `width: 100vh` to explicitly specify that you want `height` measured in terms of viewport width, and `width` in terms of viewport height.

With the correct sizing, you'll also need to change the point around which the video is rotated. Otherwise, it becomes difficult to align the edges of the video with the edges of the viewport, as shown in this expertly crafted visual example:

[image]

Following this adjustment, the last step is just to move the video upwards by a certain amount, in order to make it flush against the top of the viewport. How much is that amount? Well, the `height` of the video - which we specified as `100vw`. (I used a negative `margin-top` for this.)

Implementing these changes (and setting `object-fit: cover` so no whitespace is visible), we end up with:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0; /* Because annoying default browser margins */
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);

  transform-origin: bottom left;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  margin-top: -100vw;
  object-fit: cover;

  z-index: 4;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Beautiful Answer!

Comment: why it doesn't work on Fullscreen mode?